# changing .htaccess to skip .php from URL results in error for some web pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, web

I setup .htaccess file as follows to make elegant url by hiding .php extension;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now all of my pages work other than following three urls/pages;

```
www.auroracs.lk/about
www.auroracs.lk/enquiry
www.auroracs.lk/locate
```

for above URLS I get following error. (You may check online by trying that URL right now)

..............................
Not Found. The requested URL /about/.php was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
..............................

But if I rename about.php to about1.php then www.auroracs.lk/about1 url works. same happens to other two php files also. Can any one help why its not working only for these three pages. Is it because my .htaccess conflicting with some other file or any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your rule by this more correct rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Now I get the page but it looks styles are not applied for these three pages. But identical page with differnt url for example www.auroracs.lk/about1 works fine. Further when I type 
www.auroracs.lk/about
the URL changes to www.auroracs.lk/about/  (notice the trailing/) I wonder why it happens only for these three urls.
It work fine for other URLs for example
www.auroracs.lk/bit

Comment: If it happens to these 3 URIs only then probably these are directories also. For fixing css issue just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: I double checked and there are no folders with same name. Earlier I had wordpress site installed in the root which i uninstalled using softaculous software in CPanel, prior to uploading current site. I will check if possible caching issue too and also double check possible relative paths left. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Yes better test in a new browser also and make sure there are no other rules also.

Comment: Wow... thanks a lot..yah...when i tried with tor browser it worked also works now once browser cache is cleared....Again thank you for saving my day... :-)